# How to open checkout in new window? simplecartjs 3.0.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, checkout

I am trying to do this, but it isn't working

```
<i> extendCheckout: function (methods) {
    return simpleCart.extend(simpleCart.checkout, methods);
            },
            generateAndSendForm: function (opts) {
                var form = simpleCart.$create("form");
                form.attr('style', 'display:none;');
                form.attr('action', opts.action);
                form.attr('method', opts.method);



                simpleCart.each(opts.data, function (val, x, name) {
                    form.append(
                        simpleCart.$create("input").attr("type","hidden").attr("name",name).val(val)
                    );
                });

                simpleCart.$("body").append(form);

                form.el.submit();
                form.remove();

            }
        });

        simpleCart.extendCheckout({
            PayPal: function (opts) {
                // account email is required
                if (!opts.email) {
                    return simpleCart.error("No email provided for PayPal checkout");
                }

                // build basic form options
                var data = {
                          cmd           : "_cart"
                        , upload        : "1"
                        , currency_code : simpleCart.currency().code
                        , business      : opts.email
                        , rm            : opts.method === "GET" ? "0" : "2"
                        , tax_cart      : (simpleCart.tax()*1).toFixed(2)
                        , handling_cart : (simpleCart.shipping()*1).toFixed(2)
                        , charset       : "utf-8"



                    },
                 action = opts.sandbox ?  "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"  : "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr",  method = opts.method === "GET" ? "GET" : "POST"   ; </i>
```

I am trying using `form.target = "_blank"; target = "_blank"`  but nothing,

Demo :
https://e70f9b946472493e61425bd76235c6dfd3f4593d.googledrive.com/host/0B87ueB-BviwSUDgydXRxWi16OGM/#/

can anyone help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
form.attr('target', '_blank');
```